# Drupal incorrect node URL

Tags: url, drupal, drupal-7

My website is using Drupal. On first page I have a list of entries and each entry has own URL.

In some cases, I can't understand when, my links looks like:

```
/node/1%2C157
```

Instead of:

```
/node/1157
```

In my view I found that my content is displayed by this line:

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

I need to understand where my content is generated and to fix this problem.

Or maybe I can fix this problem from admin panel ?

( I'm using Pathauto and Path modules to rewrite URL's, on other content is working well but in some nodes I have this problem. I tried to regenerate, to remove and generate again but for this nodes nothing happened ).

Answer (score 0):

The **%2C** occurs in the url because of **comma**.Please see if you are creating any url with comma in it.This is possibly the cause of such url.

Here is the list of url encoded characters.

URL Encoded Characters

```
  backspace      %08
  tab            %09
  linefeed       %0A
  creturn        %0D
  space          %20
  !              %21
  "              %22
  #              %23
  $              %24
  %              %25
  &              %26
  '              %27
  (              %28
  )              %29
  *              %2A
  +              %2B
  ,              %2C
  -              %2D
  .              %2E
  /              %2F
  0              %30
  1              %31
  2              %32
  3              %33
  4              %34
  5              %35
  6              %36
  7              %37
  8              %38
  9              %39
  :              %3A
  ;              %3B
  <              %3C
  =              %3D
  >              %3E
  ?              %3F
  @              %40
  A              %41
  B              %42
  C              %43
  D              %44
  E              %45
  F              %46
  G              %47
  H              %48
  I              %49
  J              %4A
  K              %4B
  L              %4C
  M              %4D
  N              %4E
  O              %4F
  P              %50
  Q              %51
  R              %52
  S              %53
  T              %54
  U              %55
  V              %56
  W              %57
  X              %58
  Y              %59
  Z              %5A
  [              %5B
  \              %5C
  ]              %5D
  ^              %5E
  _              %5F
  `              %60
  a              %61
  b              %62
  c              %63
  d              %64
  e              %65
  f              %66
  g              %67
  h              %68
  i              %69
  j              %6A
  k              %6B
  l              %6C
  m              %6D
  n              %6E
  o              %6F
  p              %70
  q              %71
  r              %72
  s              %73
  t              %74
  u              %75
  v              %76
  w              %77
  x              %78
  y              %79
  z              %7A
  {              %7B
  |              %7C
  }              %7D
  ~              %7E
  ¢              %A2
  £              %A3
  ¥              %A5
  |              %A6
  §              %A7
  «              %AB
  ¬              %AC
  ¯              %AD
  º              %B0
  ±              %B1
  ª              %B2
  ,              %B4
  µ              %B5
  »              %BB
  ¼              %BC
  ½              %BD
  ¿              %BF
  À              %C0
  Á              %C1
  Â              %C2
  Ã              %C3
  Ä              %C4
  Å              %C5
  Æ              %C6
  Ç              %C7
  È              %C8
  É              %C9
  Ê              %CA
  Ë              %CB
  Ì              %CC
  Í              %CD
  Î              %CE
  Ï              %CF
  Ð              %D0
  Ñ              %D1
  Ò              %D2
  Ó              %D3
  Ô              %D4
  Õ              %D5
  Ö              %D6
  Ø              %D8
  Ù              %D9
  Ú              %DA
  Û              %DB
  Ü              %DC
  Ý              %DD
  Þ              %DE
  ß              %DF
  à              %E0
  á              %E1
  â              %E2
  ã              %E3
  ä              %E4
  å              %E5
  æ              %E6
  ç              %E7
  è              %E8
  é              %E9
  ê              %EA
  ë              %EB
  ì              %EC
  í              %ED
  î              %EE
  ï              %EF
  ð              %F0
  ñ              %F1
  ò              %F2
  ó              %F3
  ô              %F4
  õ              %F5
  ö              %F6
  ÷              %F7
  ø              %F8
  ù              %F9
  ú              %FA
  û              %FB
  ü              %FC
  ý              %FD
  þ              %FE
  ÿ              %FF
```

Comment: I think that the problems is because comma is used as thousand separator. How can I disable this ?

Comment: Please see this link for resolving the issue.https://www.drupal.org/node/52153?no_cache=1444502486